# SQL Pivot with GA4 Data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4, dynamic-pivot

This is my original query using GA4 data in bigquery to understand the depth of engagement, looking at 01/22

```
SELECT active.num_days_active, 
COUNT(DISTINCT active.user_id) AS num_users 
FROM (
  SELECT a.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.event_date) AS num_days_active
  FROM `test.events_202201*` a
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '01' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '31'
  AND stream_id = '1' OR stream_id = '2'
  GROUP BY a.user_id) AS active
LEFT JOIN `test.events_202201*` a2 ON a2.user_id = active.user_id
WHERE a2._TABLE_SUFFIX >= '01' AND a2._TABLE_SUFFIX < '31'
GROUP BY active.num_days_active
ORDER BY active.num_days_active ASC;
```

It returns this, only showing a few rows but essentially counts the number of distinct days a user_id has had an event

| num_days_active | num_users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 36491 |
| 2 | 16428 |
| 3 | 9577 |
| ... | ... |
| 31 | 22 |

**How would I pivot this**, to show this for each month of this year - I can't seem to get my head round it. Would it need to be a dynamic pivot?

In the table schema event_date is a string.

I want to return the below table, for each month of the year

| num_days_active | January | February | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36491 | 35211 |  |
| 2 | 16428 | 13445 |  |
| 3 | 9577 | 5000 |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |
| 31 | 22 | 50 |  |